# static file on django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to load static files in my project to the html template. Any help would be appreciated.
Below is my code structure.

In `setting.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/'),
]
```

In `base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/log.png' %}" alt="My image">
```

when I checked the source `src="/static/images/log.png"` it only return the error message

```
'images\log.png' could not be found.
```

An indication that the folder is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)


# Absolute paths to the directory where static files and media will be collected.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and then in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

..

# DEBUG = True
if settings.DEBUG:

    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

refer to :

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial06/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: @cizaro it worked but I have to change the absolute path to STATIC_ROOT = '/projects/static/ . Thanks